# How do I add p-values to a plotting function that I created to produce many boxplots from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I've created the plotting function below:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data
airquality$Month <- as.factor(airquality$Month)

dat1 <- airquality%>%
  filter(Month %in% c("5" , "6")) %>%
  na.omit()

#Plotting function

plotseries1<-function(yvar) {
  
  
  ggplot(dat1, aes_(x= ~Month, y= as.name(yvar))) +
    geom_boxplot(aes (fill=Month)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue")) +
    geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.03)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.15))) 
    
}

plots <- lapply(names ((dat1)[c(-5,-6)]), plotseries1)
plots
```

I would like to work out p-values using the wilcox.test and add them to the individual plots using geom_text. I'm aware that I could use stat_compare_means using the rstatix package, but the wilcoxon test in that package is not exact. I've tried the below code, but it's not working.

```
plotseries1<-function(yvar) {
  
  
  #I would like to add wilcoxon test here
  test <- wilcox.test(dat1$yvar~ dat1$Month) #I'm not sure how to get this to work
  pvalue <- test$p.value
  
  ggplot(dat1, aes_(x= ~Month, y= as.name(yvar))) +
    geom_boxplot(aes (fill=Month)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue")) +
    geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.03)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.15))) 
  
  #I would like to add p values to individual graphs using geom_text
  geom_text(data = test,
            aes(x = 1.5, y = Inf, label = format.pval(p.value, digits = 3)),   #I'm not sure if this will work
            inherit.aes = FALSE, hjust = "inward", vjust = "inward", size = 3.5) 
  
  
}
```

How do I get the plotting function to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the plot to add the p value, but to note since you have ties, exact methods may not work. for the moment I am ignoring that statistical issue and focusing on the programming to get the value on the plot. Also, `ggplot` likes data in `data.frame`, which your `test` cant be coerced to as-is, so tweaked that slightly. Aside from that, the below code should do what you want:

```
plotseries1 <- function(yvar) {
  fm <- as.formula(paste0("dat1$",yvar,"~dat1$Month"))
  test <- wilcox.test(fm, exact = FALSE) # Cant do exact as there are ties
  pvalue <- data.frame(test$p.value)
  
  ggplot(dat1, aes_(x= ~Month, y= as.name(yvar))) +
    geom_boxplot(aes (fill=Month)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue")) +
    geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.03)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.15))) +
  geom_text(data = pvalue,
            aes(x = 1.5, y = Inf, label = round(pvalue, 3)),   #I'm not sure if this will work
            inherit.aes = FALSE, hjust = "inward", vjust = "inward", size = 3.5) 
  
  
}
plot.pval <- lapply(names((dat1)[c(-5,-6)]), plotseries1)
plot.pval
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jpsmith, this was very helpful. I was also hoping to find out how to move the p-value slightly lower and off the top edge of the plot. I tried playing around with hjust and vjust,  but the p-value just moves off the graph.

Comment: Try changing the `ylab` in `geom_text` from `Inf` to wherever you want it on the y axis - `x` and `y` tell it where to put the text

Comment: I've tried to play around with the ylab, but each plot has its own (very different) y-axis. Is there a way I could add each p-value slightly below the border in each individual graph?